# Why does Kundt’s tube produce striations?

Tags: waves, acoustics

[image]

Why does the [Kundt’s tube](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kundt%27s_tube) form these striations? I am looking for the simplest answer possible.

Comment: That wikipedia-link says: "The powder is caught up in the moving air and settles in little piles or lines at these nodes, because the air is still and quiet there." I doubt there is a more simple answer.

Comment: @Pieter maybe you are right. I wonder why they do form these stripes though. Instead of simply mounting together.

Answer (score 0):

So the question was why the small spheres do not simply pile up at the nodes of the standing wave, where the air velocity is low.

I guess the styrofoam balls may acquire some charge by friction, repel each other, and cling to the tube (glass or plastic).

Comment: Thanks, that’s an excellent guess. I just found [this paper](https://www.ld-didactic.de/literatur/hb/e/p1/p1731_e.pdf) which may give some hints at additional reasons too: “transverse stripes form in the antinodes, caused by the circulation flow between the wall of the tube and the tube axis”.